# Shake: How to reliably, automatically force rebuild when my rules change, becoming out of sync with the shake database?

Tags: shake-build-system

Shake has `shakeVersion :: String`:

> Defaults to 1. The version number of your build rules. **Change the version number** to force a complete rebuild, **such as when making significant changes to the rules that require a wipe**. The version number should be set in the source code, and not passed on the command line.

It is incredibly easy to improve the build system a bit and not notice that they were *significant changes that require a wipe*. If you distribute those via version control, it can lead to incorrect builds of my co-workers and in my Continuous Integration bot.

While I fix my own build by removing `.shake.database`, communicating this to a whole company is not fun.

How can I deal with this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I managed to come up with in https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/59; it is probably easier to spot it on stackoverflow than in a closed issue:

---

Let's assume my Shake rules are in `Build.hs`.

I use a hash of `Build.hs` itself as `shakeVersion`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Development.Shake.Classes (hashWithSalt)
import Language.Haskell.TH

-- | The name of this file we are in.
_THIS_FILE_NAME :: String
_THIS_FILE_NAME = $(LitE . StringL . loc_filename <$> location)

main = do
  checksum <- dropWhile (== '-') . show . hashWithSalt 0 <$> BS.readFile _THIS_FILE_NAME

  shakeArgs shakeOptions
      { shakeVersion = "hash-" ++ checksum ++ "-" ++ _THIS_FILE_NAME
      } $ do ...
```

This way the version will be automatically changed when I change my Shake code, and I never have to worry about bumping it manually.

---

**UPDATE:** There is now a function [`getHashedShakeVersion`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.15/shake-0.15.11/Development-Shake.html#v:getHashedShakeVersion) in `shake` that allows to do the below a bit more easily.

Comment: I've updated the code to use `hashWithSalt` from `hashable`, re-exported from `Shake.Classes`.